# How can I search for a specific key in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

So I got this dictionary from a csv file and I would like to look for a specific key inside this dictionary (actually the og idea was to search for said key in the csv file and then make a dictionary from that key down) but I don't really know how to do it.

So far I got:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    dict = df.to_dict(orient='dict')
    for index, line in enumerate(dict):
        if "Wavelength [nm]" in line:
         print(index)
```

The idea is to know the index of "Wavelength".

Comment: Is "Wavelength [nm]" a key or a value? Also, do you just need to know if it exists?

Comment: Wavelength is a key. I want to track it so I can get his index.

Comment: Python dictionaries don't really have a concept of indexes. You could enumerate a dictionary's keys and determine a position (Nth iteration) but to what end?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value of a key without knowing whether it's in the dict, often the most natural way is

```
value = dict.get( key, defaultvalue)
```

`defaultvalue` is what you would set value to in your code once you had established that the key is not present. Often, `None`, or an empty list or tuple.

If you just waht to check whether the key is present without accessing the value, use

```
if key in dict:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```py
if key in dict:
    print(key,dict[key])
```

Comment: You don't need the additional call to the `keys` method. A simple `if key in dict` is enough.